# Convert v8::String to LPCWSTR?

Tags: c++, string, types, v8

So I'm passing a string value as function argument from runtime:

```
Handle<Value> xObj::Whatever(const Arguments& args){ ... // etc.
```

`args[0]` should definitely be string:

```
      if(!args[0]->IsString()) { ThrowException(... // etc.
```

Now that we have that, how do I convert it into something useful like LPCWSTR, wchar_t, char[] or whatever?

```
      MessageBox(NULL, args[0], L"Your value, sir.",0); // no way
      MessageBox(NULL, args[0]->ToString(), L"Your value, sir.",0); // also no
      /// then how?
```

Comment: The `GetExternalStringResource()` method returns an `ExternalStringResource`. You can call `data()` on this returned string resource to get a `const char *`. Make sure that you check if `IsExternal` is true before working with the string resource i.e. calling the member `data()`. Or, do you need a wide string?

Comment: To convert to wide string, you can use things like the A2W macro.

Comment: @dirkgently it's a `const uint16_t * ::ExternalStringResource::data ()` what do I do with it?

Comment: Dang! Wrong link. You can probably use [ExternalAsciiStringResource](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1String_1_1ExternalAsciiStringResource.html).

Comment: Not sure what trying to do here?  Not sure why using constants are a limitation in MessageBox.  Contants are easy to use and nonconstraining.  Do not need variables in places of constants for any if then scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v8::String::Value(args[0])` can be casted to a `uint16_t const*`, which either is, or can be casted to `LPCWSTR`. (This depends on compiler setting `/Zc:wchar_t-`)

Comment: `LPCWSTR msg = (LPCWSTR) * String::Value(args[0]->ToString()); MessageBox(NULL, msg , L"Your value, sir.",0);` messes up the first few characters of UTF-8 encoded strings.

Comment: You shouldn't have any UTF-8 characters? The W in `LPCWSTR` stands for Wide (UTF-16).

Comment: It worked with `String::Utf8Value` and `MultiByteToWideChar()`

Comment: `/Zc:wchar_t-` is not recommended by Microsoft. So is it legal to simply cast the `*value` to `wchar_t *` or how's that correlated with the compiler option?

Comment: @Andy: It's not a portable cast, but then again, neither is `LPCWSTR`