# How to cast v8::value to LPCSTR

Tags: c++, node.js

I am trying to make a node add on and copying some C++ code over. One line is giving me an error

```
    void Attach(const FunctionCallbackInfo <Value> &args) {
        Isolate *isolate = args.GetIsolate();

        HWND target = FindWindowA(NULL, args[0]);

    ...
```

The javascript usage is

```
    const title = window.getTitle();

    const attach = addon.attach(title)
```

where 'window' is an instance of BrowserWindow from electron

with error

```
'HWND FindWindowA(LPCSTR,LPCSTR)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'v8::Local<v8::Value>' to 'LPCSTR'
```

I do understand casting but I have very limited understanding/experience with Windows, C++ and this is my first time experimenting with an addon.

I found an answer here [Convert v8::String to LPCWSTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132212/convert-v8string-to-lpcwstr) but I was not able to make sense of it.

Comment: I suggest that you add some code to clarify the context of `args`

Comment: @AndreasDM Added the start of the function, to be honest I don't even know what is isolate or what does GetIsolate() do, but I did test and know that args[0] does hold the value I expect when I used ```args.GetReturnValue().Set(args[0]);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on a forum in French https://zestedesavoir.com/forums/sujet/13978/c-probleme-de-conversion-de-type-stringchar/.

```
        Isolate *isolate = args.GetIsolate();

        Local<Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();

        Local<String> appName = args[0].As<String>();

        CHAR* charAppName = new CHAR[128];

        (*appName)->WriteUtf8(isolate, charAppName);

        HWND target = FindWindowA(NULL, charAppName);
```

This allows me to compile without error and the add on works as expected. Though I do not understand at all what each line is doing.